# Java Reading from a File using FileChannel

Tags: java, file, io, nio, filechannel

I've been getting some strange outputs from this code upon reading from a large file, the file was printed using a while loop to 99,999 digits however, upon reading the file and printing the contents it only outputs 99,988 lines. Also, is using a ByteBuffer the only option for reading back the file? I've seen some other code using a CharBuffer, but I'm not sure which one I should use, and in what cases I should use them.
NOTE: filePath is a Path object pointing to a file on the disk.

```
    private void byteChannelTrial() throws Exception {
        try (FileChannel channel = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(filePath, READ)) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
            while (channel.read(buffer) != -1) {
                buffer.rewind();
                System.out.print(Charset.forName(encoding).decode(buffer));
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That code should print the entire contents of the file correctly. Is it printing what it does print correctly? and have you considered using a `BufferedReader` wrapped around an `InputStreamReader` wrapped around a `FileInputStream`?

Comment: Are you counting digits or lines (you mention both)? Also, how are you determining the number of lines written?

Comment: Every new integer corresponds with a line. So the number count is the line count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, flip() is called before buffer data is read. the rewind() method does bellowing works:

```
public final Buffer rewind() {
    position = 0;
    mark = -1;
    return this;
}
```

it does not set the 'limit' as flip() does:

```
public final Buffer flip() {
    limit = position;
    position = 0;
    mark = -1;
    return this;
}
```

So, take a tray using flip() instead of rewind() before reading.

Answer (score 1):

For reading text BufferedReader is the best

```
    try (BufferedReader rdr = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path"),
            Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        for (String line; (line = rdr.readLine()) != null;) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

BTW

```
String encoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
Charset.forName(encoding);
```

is equivalent to

```
Charset.defaultCharset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it actually turns out that this combination works:

```
    private void byteChannelTrial() throws Exception {
        try (FileChannel channel = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(this.filePath, READ)) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            while (channel.read(buffer) != -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                System.out.print(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer));
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

As to why it works, i am not quite certain.

Comment: It works because you are calling `flip()` instead of `rewind()`, as per @horaceman's answer.

Comment: For reference this code may fail to decode multi-byte chars, or with combining chars (diacritics, emojis) on buffer limit because the bytes may be incomplete in the current buffer. This will typically happen with UTF-8 encoding.